# I am having issues with Array to JSON structure in PHP to be used in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I always struggle with Array to JSON formatting.  I am using a selectbox plugin from TexoTela.  The plugin requires a json structure as:

```
{
    "ajax1": "AJAX option 1",
    "ajax2": "AJAX option 2",
    "ajax3": "AJAX option 3"
}
```

My php code:

```
    function get_selectfield_list($col, $table)
    {
        $location_list = array();

        //create an sql string and set it to the $sql variable
        $sql = "SELECT id, $col FROM $table";

        //form the sql query and set it to the $query variable
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        //loop through the result_array and set the results to the $location_list array
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $value = $row['id']; //set the database table id to to $value variable
            $text = $row[$col]; //set the the $string value to the $text variable
            $location_list = array($value => $text); //form the $location_list array with the the $value and $text values
        }

        echo json_encode($location_list); //convert the $location_list array into a json object and return it.                              
    }
```

My PHP code returns `{"4":"chickenpen 4"}`

Instead of `{"4":"chickenpen 4","5":"chickenpen 5", etc....}`

I think that is due to the code: $location_list = array($value => $text);  Every time the foreach loops it creates a new array.  How do I format the array to output all the results in the foreach instead of the last result?

-Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    $location_list[$value] = $text;
```