# loop through php within Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, json

I am running a javascript file either on my hard drive or from my website, right now, I have been trying to get this to work from my hard drive.  The javascript loops through and builds a table with x number of rows.  Each row has a "textarea" box where users can type in mutual funds ticker symbols.  I would like to populate the textarea boxes with data from a mysql database.  From the advice I got from Will, I am using a PHP file to return JSON, but I can't figure out how to iterate through the JSON and put one fund symbol in each row of my javascript table.

below is my php file on my website

```
<?php
$connect = >>>>>my connection string here<<<<<;
mysql_select_db("altatech_grid");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FSymbol FROM FundSymbols"); 
$to_encode = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $to_encode[] = $row['FSymbol'];
} 
$myFund = json_encode($to_encode);
echo ($myFund);
?>
```

which returns this below <<<<<<

```
["FDGRX","FVINX","VCVLX","LLPFX "]
```

this is my javascript below <<<<<<<

```
document.write("<table>");
nButtons = 0;
for (row = 1; row < nItems; row++)
{
document.write("<tr>");
for (rowButton = 0; rowButton < row; rowButton++)
document.write("<td><textarea class='unorderedlist' wrap='soft' name='possibility" + (row+1) + "' id='p" + (row+1) + "'>")";
########### This Is Where The PHP Needs To Put One Item In Each Row ############
document.write("</textarea></td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</table>");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am having issues with Array to JSON structure in PHP to be used in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584997/i-am-having-issues-with-array-to-json-structure-in-php-to-be-used-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't JSON, it's an array...

```
var i;
var html = "<textarea>";
var symbols = ["FDGRX","FVINX","VCVLX","LLPFX"];
for (i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    html += symbols[i] + "\r\n";
}
var html += "</textarea>";
document.write(html);
```

JSON objects look like this:

```
var jsonObject = { name: "John", location: "UK" };
```

And you could add your dynamic values like this:

```
var symbols = <?php echo $myFund; ?>;
```

Comment: +1 for providing the correct way to iterate trough the array, however care to elaborate how exactly this isn't JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure what I am supposed to use for "var symbols = ???;  which is hardcoded in the example above but can't be hardcoded because they will always change depending on what the php file returns from the database

Comment: I presume you would replace the hard-coded value with... <?php echo ($myFund); ?> - which you said outputs the hard-coded string I put in the example.

Comment: @Michael J.V. good idea - example added. @user695129 example added :)

Comment: thanks again for your help, the problem is that $myFund represents an array, so I would have to iterate through each item in the array.  I am going to try to re-do this as a php file and run the code from the server and build the html page from the php code, then go to the javascript for other functions after the html page is built and populated with data from the database

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no way to do like you want. Because, PHP is script run at server. So you could not run a PHP script from client using Javascript.
But you can do like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($to_encode);?>;
    //At client it will be:
    //var data = ["FDGRX","FVINX","VCVLX","LLPFX"];
    //Then you can loop:
    for(var row = 0; row < data.length; row++)
    {
        //@Todo
        //.................
        document.write(data[row]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Something seems to be missing in the answer above.  If I any running through the JavaScript and I get to the point where I need to pull in the PHP data, do I say
"var data = <?php src="http:///mywebsite/query_v3.php" echo json_encode($to_encode);?>;"
so that the JavaScript knows where to find the php file, or should I be running the javascript from the same website location where the php file is located?